# Kotlin - get T::class.java from class generic type parameter

Tags: kotlin, corda

I'm trying to build a generic repository around Corda's vault. It should look something like this:

```
class VaultRepository<out T : ContractState>(private val services: CordaRPCOps) {

    fun getUnconsumedStateByExternalId(externalId: String): T {
        return services.vaultQuery<T>(...).states.single().state.data
    }
}
```

But I get this error:

> Cannot use 'T' as reified type parameter

I could use another `vaultQuery` function, which takes a `Class<T>` instead as a parameter, but I need to be able to get it from `VaultRepository<T>` first.

Is there a way to get T from a classes generic type parameter list?

Comment: Is that type parameter only relevant in the depicted method? You could make T a reified method type parameter instead

Comment: @s1m0nw1 no, T will be relevant in lots of methods. I could make all of the methods take T (no pun intended) rather than the class, but I feel that it's counter productive when T is the same throughout the class. - I'm guessing this is either difficult or impossible due to JVM's compile time type erasure? (I come from C#, where the CLR is fully type aware, even when it comes to GTPs, so this would be trivial)

Comment: https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/reified-type-parameters-in-classes/1567/7

Comment: I have a similar problem here [Modularising to create a function with variable Types in Kotlin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66961161/modularising-to-create-a-function-with-variable-types-in-kotlin). Can you please help.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

My go-to solution is to add a `Class<T>` parameter to the primary constructor and a constructor-like function which gets the `Class` from `reified T`.

```
class VaultRepository<out T : ContractState>(
    private val services: CordaRPCOps,
    private val clazz: Class<T>
) {
    fun getUnconsumedStateByExternalId(externalId: String): T {
        return services.vaultQuery(..., clazz).states.single().state.data
    }
}

fun VaultRepository<reified T : ContractState>(services: CordaRPCOps) =
    VaultRepository(services, T::class.java)
```

To anticipate a specific comment: some people think `fun`s shouldn't look like constructors. [The Kotlin team doesn't agree.](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/coding-conventions.html#function-names)

Comment: This is a nice way to provide the desired behaviour although I don’t agree with the constructor-like looking of funs. ++

Comment: @s1m0nw1 I am a big fan of Scala's uniform access principle and this is the one case in which Kotlin extends it even further.

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov I like this, though I did move the contructor-like function to a `companion object` and renamed it `createRepository`.

Comment: I have a similar problem here [Modularising to create a function with variable Types in Kotlin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66961161/modularising-to-create-a-function-with-variable-types-in-kotlin). Can you please help.