# Modularising to create a function with variable Types in Kotlin

Tags: function, kotlin, generics

I have a funtion like this in many places in my project

```
class ClubsViewModel():  BaseViewModel() {
    private var _mClubs = MutableLiveData<ArrayList<ClubFSEntity>>()
    ...

    private fun listenToFireStoreClubs() {
        mFirestore.collection("Clubs").addSnapshotListener { snapshot, e ->
            // if there is an exception we want to skip.
            if (e != null) {
                return@addSnapshotListener
            }
            // if we are here, we did not encounter an exception
            if (snapshot != null) {
                val allClubs = ArrayList<ClubFSEntity>()
                snapshot.documents.forEach {
                    it.toObject(ClubFSEntity::class.java)?.let {
        
                        allClubs.add(it)
                    }
                }
                _mClubs.value = allClubs
            }
        }
    }
}
...
...
class ProjectsViewModel():  BaseViewModel() {
    private var _mProjects = MutableLiveData<ArrayList<ProjectsFSEntity>>()

    private fun listenToFireStoreProjects() {
        //Code Here is Similar to the Code in the similar function in ClubsViewModel.
    }
}
...
...
open class BaseViewModel() : ViewModel()  {
    protected val mFirestore = Firebase.firestore
    protected var mStorageReferenence: StorageReference

    protected val _networkState = MutableLiveData<NetworkState>()
    protected val networkState: LiveData<NetworkState> = _networkState

    //I would like to make this function private to access the above variables.
    inline fun listenToFireStoreCollection[TO MOVE HERE SO THAT ALL MY OTHER VIEW MODELS CAN CALL IT]
}
...
...
@Parcelize
data class ClubFSEntity(val title: String="",
                        val description: String="",
                        val startDate: String?=null,
                        var clubId : String=""): Parcelable
```

It's easy to modularize out the **`"Clubs"`** parameter. The Firebase data from that document list goes to an arraylist of **`ClubFSEntity`** data objects. When adding the Firebase snapshot data to the **`allClubs`** array, we convert using **`ClubFSEntity::class.java`**.

I have many places with this same code, but only three things change (**`"Clubs"`**, **`ClubFSEntity`** and **`ClubFSEntity::class.java`**). I would like to create a function with those three items as a variables.

I don't even know what to search for. I have tried to use generics but can't get it so far.

I would like to also use a generic class if possible.

I would prefer to initialize the ViewModel like so:

```
class ClubsFragment : Fragment() {
  private val mClubsViewModel: ClubsViewModel<ClubsFSEntity> by viewModels()

}
```

And, to change the ViewModel definition to something like:

```
class ClubsViewModel<T> () :  BaseViewModel() {

    private var _mClubs = MutableLiveData<List<T>>()
...
}
```

Each view model would call `listenToFirestoreCollection` with its own parameter(s).

Comment: Sorry for the off topic, but is there a reason you're using `ArrayList` explicitly in your `LiveData` instead of just `List`? Because you could simply use `map` instead of that `forEach` + `add`

Comment: Thanks. I have adopted that. Didn't know how to use the map.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's first simplify your initial function:

```kotlin
private var _mClubs = MutableLiveData<List<ClubFSEntity>>()

private fun listenToFireStoreClubs() {
    mFirestore.collection("Clubs").addSnapshotListener { snapshot, e ->
        // if there is an exception we want to skip.
        if (e != null) {
            return@addSnapshotListener
        }
        // if we are here, we did not encounter an exception
        if (snapshot != null) {
            _mClubs.value = snapshot.documents.mapNotNull { 
                it.toObject(ClubFSEntity::class.java)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You could make it more generic like this:

```kotlin
private fun <T> listenToFireStoreCollection(
    collectionName: String,
    liveData: MutableLiveData<List<T>>,
    clazz: Class<T>,
) {
    mFirestore.collection(collectionName).addSnapshotListener { snapshot, e ->
        // if there is an exception we want to skip.
        if (e != null) {
            return@addSnapshotListener
        }
        // if we are here, we did not encounter an exception
        if (snapshot != null) {
            liveData.value = snapshot.documents.mapNotNull { it.toObject(clazz) }
        }
    }
}
```

You can also go one step further and additionally define a reified version of this, so you don't have to pass in the `Class<T>` explicitly each time:

```kotlin
private inline fun <reified T> listenToFireStoreCollection(
    collectionName: String,
    liveData: MutableLiveData<List<T>>,
) = listenToFireStoreCollection(collectionName, liveData, T::class.java)
```

If the live data and the function are in the same class, you can also make the class generic itself like the following:

```kotlin
class FireStoreLiveData<T>(
    val collectionName: String,
    val clazz: Class<T>,
) {
    private var _mClubs = MutableLiveData<List<ClubFSEntity>>()

    private fun listenToFireStoreCollection() {
        mFirestore.collection(collectionName).addSnapshotListener { snapshot, e ->
            // if there is an exception we want to skip.
            if (e != null) {
                return@addSnapshotListener
            }
            // if we are here, we did not encounter an exception
            if (snapshot != null) {
                liveData.value = snapshot.documents.mapNotNull { it.toObject(clazz) }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But it's hard to tell how to design the API of this class without more info about how you intend to use it from outside (everything is private right now, so not much use).
For instance, who starts the listener? Is there a way to stop it? etc.

Comment: wanted to avoid passing the object name in the function name. could we use `(..,liveData: MutableLiveData<List<T>>,...)`

Comment: `ClubFSEntity` is different for each different call.

Comment: This is what i get

```Type mismatch.
Required:
List<ClubFSEntity>?
Found:
List<T!!>```

Comment: Maybe i can make the whole class generic and declare clubs like this:: `private var _mClubs = MutableLiveData<ArrayList<T>>()`

Comment: I will give u a chance to edit the final part to contain the COMPLETE solution, but, I was able to reach it using your directions. If you fail, i may complete your solution then mark as correct.

Comment: Plus, can you please show me how i can use a generic in the Class Holding the entire Code please, so that my initial declaration is like this `private var _mClubs = MutableLiveData<List<R>>()` , holding class declaration is like this `class clubsViewModel<R>(){... }`

Comment: Yes of course it should be `T` in the live data parameter. This was just a typo on my part.

Comment: Is it possible to use a generic class then still use `T::class.java`, i have failed so far. I could modify the question to include that instead of asking a new one.

Comment: Ah yes it should be possible too, I didn't have the extra context in the question about what parts you wanted to make generic. Everything is private in the question, so indeed it looks self-contained. It would help to have more context about how you use the class containing these declarations. What is the exact problem you are facing? Who is calling `listenToFireStoreCollection`?

Comment: I have modified the question to include the classes and context.

Comment: I have an extension of the problem here. Didn't include it here because it's unrelated: [Hilt Dependency injection with Class<T> in ViewModel Constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66988538/hilt-dependency-injection-with-classt-in-viewmodel-constructor)

Answer (score 0):

I finished like this:

```
class ClubsViewModel<T> (clazz: Class<T>) :  BaseViewModel<T>(clazz) {      //<<  THIS IS WHERE THE CURRENT PROBLEM WAS.

    private var _mClubs = MutableLiveData<List<T>>()
     listenToFireStoreCollection("Clubs", _mClubs)

...
}

class BViewModel<T> (clazz: Class<T>) :  BaseViewModel<T>(clazz) {          //<<   THIS IS WHERE THE CURRENT PROBLEM WAS.

    private var _mBs = MutableLiveData<List<T>>()
    listenToFireStoreCollection("Bname", _mBs)
...
}

class BaseViewModel<T>(val clazz: Class<T>) {
    protected val mFirestore = Firebase.firestore

    protected  fun listenToFireStoreCollection(val collectionName: String, liveData: MutableLiveData<List<T>>) 
        mFirestore.collection(collectionName).addSnapshotListener { snapshot, e ->
            // if there is an exception we want to skip.
            if (e != null) {
                return@addSnapshotListener
            }
            // if we are here, we did not encounter an exception
            if (snapshot != null) {
                liveData.value = snapshot.documents.mapNotNull { it.toObject(clazz) }
            }
        }
    }
}
//FRAGMENT EXAMPLES.
class ClubsFragment : Fragment() {

    private val mClubsViewModel: ClubsViewModel<ClubsFSEntity> by viewModels()
...
}
class BsFragment : Fragment() {

    private val mBsViewModel: BsViewModel<BsFSEntity> by viewModels()
...
}
```